# How to get capability list for existing MacOs application

Tags: macos, app-id

How can I get the capability list (https://developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities/) for existing MacOs application?
Planning to register AppId and want to compare my list with existsing application.

Regards,
Pavel

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, you can inspect embedded.provisionprofile for the "Entitlements" key and get the list of entitlements, example from Google Chrome profile

```
<key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains.applinks.read-write</key>
        <true/>
                
                <key>com.apple.application-identifier</key>
        <string>EQHXZ8M8AV.com.google.Chrome</string>
                
                <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
                <string>EQHXZ8M8AV.*</string>
        </array>
                
                <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
        <string>EQHXZ8M8AV</string>

    </dict>
```